# MYSQL : Importing an XML data file using LOAD XML

Tags: mysql, xml

I'm trying to load a couple of XML formats into a common table structure and am having problems with one of them which contains the following XML data:

```
<payslip >
  <address >
    <addressee >XXXXX YYYYY</addressee>
    <line >167 High Road</line>
    <line >Walthamstow</line>
    <line >London</line>
    <line >E17 5DD      [201567 ]</line>
    <ifundelivered >3738 XYZ Limited  Herring Court  27 - 29 Frobisher Street  Dulwich  London  WC2B 3SS</ifundelivered></address>
  <employer >
    <name >3738 XYZ Limited</name>
    <taxdistrict >406</taxdistrict>
    <taxref >LA99999</taxref></employer>
  <employee >
    <payroll >3799-</payroll>
    <userid >3799-201567</userid>
    <number >201567</number>
    <name >XXXXX YYYYY</name>
    <deptnumber >0001</deptnumber>
    <deptname >2000</deptname>
    <taxcode >1150L</taxcode>
    <NINO >QQ104330Q</NINO>
    <NItable >A</NItable>
    <email >xxxxx.yyyyy@qqqqqq.co.uk</email></employee>
  <period >
    <paydate >2017-08-11</paydate>
    <taxperiod type = "week" >20</taxperiod></period>
  <elements >
    <element amount = "1572.62" position = "gross" title = "Salary"/>
    <element amount = "-470.00" position = "adjust" title = "P.A.Y.E." ytd = "1399.80"/>
    <element amount = "1741.00" position = "gross" title = "Perf Bonus"/>
    <element amount = "-312.84" position = "adjust" title = "N.I." ytd = "994.34"/>
    <element amount = "-78.63" position = "gross" rate = "-78.6300" title = "Unpaid Sick" units = "1.0000"/>
    <element amount = "-1.00" position = "adjust" title = "RDC" ytd = "3.00"/>
  </elements>
  <totals >
    <gross >3234.99</gross>
    <adjustments >-783.84</adjustments>
    <nett >2451.15</nett></totals>
  <notations >
    <thisemployment title = "NIable Pay" ytd = "11426.14"/>
    <thisemployment title = "Taxable Pay" ytd = "11426.14"/>
    <thisemployment title = "Tax deduct." ytd = "1399.80"/>
    <prevemployment title = "Pay" ytd = "0.00"/>
    <prevemployment title = "Tax deduct." ytd = "0.00"/>
    <employer thisrun = "359.76" title = "Nat. Ins." ytd = "1143.48"/>
    <employer thisrun = "0.00" title = "Pension" ytd = "15.73"/>
  </notations>
  <comments >
    <line >2451.15 paid by BACS.  **-*7-13 A/c ****3333</line>
  </comments>
</payslip>
```

I'm unable to assign variables to elements within difference sections. e.g. element 'name' appears in the 'employee' and 'employer' sections and I'm unable to differentiate the sections to assign the variable to a column.

```
LOAD XML local INFILE 'I:/PAYSLIPS37380004.xml'
INTO TABLE test.temp_payslips
    rows identified by '<payslip>'
    (@NINO,
    @number)

SET Payrollrunid=1,
    isLive=1,
    print=0,
    NINumber=@NINO,
    EmployeeNumber=@number;
```

I have tried prefixing the variable with the section (e.g. @employee.number) but this doesn't work.  Any ideas?

I also need to create a records in a sub-table (paysliptrans) based on the data within the 'elements' section.  The code I'd like to use is:

```
LOAD XML local INFILE 'I:/PAYSLIPS37380004.xml'
INTO TABLE pmdata_test.temp_paysliptrans rows identified by '<elements>'
    (@title,
    @amount,
    @position,
    @rate,
    @units,
    @ytd)

SET PayslipID=(select payslipid from pmdata_test.temp_payslips where EmployeeNumber=@number),
    Name=@title,
    Type="P",
    Total=@amount,
    Rate=@rate,
    Units=@units,
    YTD=@ytd;
```

But I still have the same problem in that it won't pull out the @number (employee) which is required to get the payslipID data in order to populate the paysliptrans.payslipID field.

Other information:

### temp_payslips table

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_payslips` (
  `PayslipID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PayrollRunID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EmployeeID` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmployeeNumber` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FirstName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmployeeName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AddressName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address3` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address4` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address5` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PostCode` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompanyName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Department` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CostCentre` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CostCentreDesc` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LocationName` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PayDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `PeriodNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PayFrequency` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PayMethod` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrintPayslip` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TaxCode` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TaxBasis` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NINumber` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NICode` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GrossPay` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GrossPayYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GrossTaxPayYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TaxPaidYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Deductions` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeductionsYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NETPay` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NETPayYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BankName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BankSortCode` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BankAccount` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BuildingSocNum` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Message` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HolidayEntitlement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HolidayTakenThisPeriod` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HolidayRemaining` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ERSPen` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OutputPrint` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OutputEmail` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OutputSMS` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OutputPortal` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeliveryType` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeliveryGroup` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompanyCode` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmployerPension` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmployerPensionYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmployeePension` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmployeePensionYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Misc1Pension` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Misc1PensionYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Misc2Pension` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Misc2PensionYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TaxYear` year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `P45GrossforTax` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `P45Tax` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmployeeNIYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmployerNI` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmployerNIYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GrossforNI` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GrossforNIYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SSPYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SMPYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SPPYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SAPYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ASPPYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AllSPYTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SortSeq` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tempId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `superceded` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `isLive` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `print` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `UUID` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PayslipID`,`PayrollRunID`,`EmployeeNumber`),
  KEY `PayDate` (`PayDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### temp_paysliptrans table

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_paysliptrans` (
  `PayslipTranID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PayslipID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pstOrder` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Units` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rate` decimal(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Total` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `YTD` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Nontaxable` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserDefInt1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserDefDec1` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PayslipTranID`,`PayslipID`,`Type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Could also share the table structures for tables.`temp_payslips` and `temp_paysliptrans`...  maybe i understand then want you are trying to import from the xml.. The second IMPORT query is clear your want to load data from the elements tag.. The first IMPORT query isn't that clear..

Comment: I have added the Create SQL for the 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

Loading of the XML files could be achieved as follows:

File: `/path/to/file/PAYSLIPS37380004.xml`:

```xml
<payslip>
  <address>
    <addressee>XXXXX YYYYY</addressee>
    <line>167 High Road</line>
    <line>Walthamstow</line>
    <line>London</line>
    <line>E17 5DD      [201567 ]</line>
    <ifundelivered>3738 XYZ Limited  Herring Court  27 - 29 Frobisher Street  Dulwich  London  WC2B 3SS</ifundelivered>
  </address>
  <employer>
    <name>3738 XYZ Limited</name>
    <taxdistrict>406</taxdistrict>
    <taxref>LA99999</taxref>
  </employer>
  <employee>
    <payroll>3799-</payroll>
    <userid>3799-201567</userid>
    <number>201567</number>
    <name>XXXXX YYYYY</name>
    <deptnumber>0001</deptnumber>
    <deptname>2000</deptname>
    <taxcode>1150L</taxcode>
    <NINO>QQ104330Q</NINO>
    <NItable>A</NItable>
    <email>xxxxx.yyyyy@qqqqqq.co.uk</email>
  </employee>
  <period>
    <paydate>2017-08-11</paydate>
    <taxperiod type="week">20</taxperiod>
  </period>
  <elements>
    <element amount="1572.62" position="gross" title="Salary"/>
    <element amount="-470.00" position="adjust" title="P.A.Y.E." ytd="1399.80"/>
    <element amount="1741.00" position="gross" title="Perf Bonus"/>
    <element amount="-312.84" position="adjust" title="N.I." ytd="994.34"/>
    <element amount="-78.63" position="gross" rate="-78.6300" title="Unpaid Sick" units="1.0000"/>
    <element amount="-1.00" position="adjust" title="RDC" ytd="3.00"/>
  </elements>
  <totals>
    <gross>3234.99</gross>
    <adjustments>-783.84</adjustments>
    <nett>2451.15</nett>
  </totals>
  <notations>
    <thisemployment title="NIable Pay" ytd="11426.14"/>
    <thisemployment title="Taxable Pay" ytd="11426.14"/>
    <thisemployment title="Tax deduct." ytd="1399.80"/>
    <prevemployment title="Pay" ytd="0.00"/>
    <prevemployment title="Tax deduct." ytd="0.00"/>
    <employer thisrun="359.76" title="Nat. Ins." ytd="1143.48"/>
    <employer thisrun="0.00" title="Pension" ytd="15.73"/>
  </notations>
  <comments>
    <line>2451.15 paid by BACS.  **-*7-13 A/c ****3333</line>
  </comments>
</payslip>
```

MySQL Command Line:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.19    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `temp_paysliptrans`,
    ->                      `temp_payslips`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp_payslips` (
    ->   `PayslipID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `PayrollRunID` INT NOT NULL,
    ->   `isLive` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    ->   `print` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `EmployeeNumber` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `NINumber` VARCHAR(9) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`PayslipID`, `PayrollRunID`, `EmployeeNumber`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp_paysliptrans` (
    ->   `PayslipTranID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `PayslipID` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `Name` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `Type` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `Total` DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `Rate` DECIMAL(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `Units` DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `YTD` DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`PayslipTranID`, `PayslipID`, `Type`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE
    ->   '/path/to/file/PAYSLIPS37380004.xml'
    ->   INTO TABLE `temp_payslips`
    ->   ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<employee>'
    ->   (
    ->     @`NINO`,
    ->     @`number`
    ->   )
    ->   SET `Payrollrunid` = 1,
    ->       `isLive` = 1,
    ->       `print` = 0,
    ->       `NINumber` = @`NINO`,
    ->       `EmployeeNumber` = @`number`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `PayslipID`,
    ->   `PayrollRunID`,
    ->   `isLive`,
    ->   `print`,
    ->   `EmployeeNumber`,
    ->   `NINumber`
    -> FROM
    ->   `temp_payslips`;
+-----------+--------------+--------+-------+----------------+-----------+
| PayslipID | PayrollRunID | isLive | print | EmployeeNumber | NINumber  |
+-----------+--------------+--------+-------+----------------+-----------+
|         1 |            1 |      1 |     0 | 201567         | QQ104330Q |
+-----------+--------------+--------+-------+----------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE
    ->   '/path/to/file/PAYSLIPS37380004.xml'
    ->   INTO TABLE `temp_paysliptrans`
    ->   ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<element>'
    ->   (
    ->     @`title`,
    ->     @`amount`,
    ->     @`position`,
    ->     @`rate`,
    ->     @`units`,
    ->     @`ytd`
    ->   )
    ->   SET `Name` = @`title`,
    ->       `Type` = 'P',
    ->       `Total` = @`amount`,
    ->       `Rate` = @`rate`,
    ->       `Units` = @`units`,
    ->       `YTD` = @`ytd`;
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `PayslipTranID`,
    ->   `PayslipID`,
    ->   `Name`,
    ->   `Type`,
    ->   `Total`,
    ->   `Rate`,
    ->   `Units`,
    ->   `YTD`
    -> FROM
    ->   `temp_paysliptrans`;
+---------------+-----------+-------------+------+---------+----------+-------+---------+
| PayslipTranID | PayslipID | Name        | Type | Total   | Rate     | Units | YTD     |
+---------------+-----------+-------------+------+---------+----------+-------+---------+
|             1 |         0 | Salary      | P    | 1572.62 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL |
|             2 |         0 | P.A.Y.E.    | P    | -470.00 |     NULL |  NULL | 1399.80 |
|             3 |         0 | Perf Bonus  | P    | 1741.00 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL |
|             4 |         0 | N.I.        | P    | -312.84 |     NULL |  NULL |  994.34 |
|             5 |         0 | Unpaid Sick | P    |  -78.63 | -78.6300 |  1.00 |    NULL |
|             6 |         0 | RDC         | P    |   -1.00 |     NULL |  NULL |    3.00 |
+---------------+-----------+-------------+------+---------+----------+-------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, your requirement needs more effort, because you must insert the value of `PayslipID` column of `temp_payslips` table in `PayslipID` column of `temp_paysliptrans` table, an alternative is shown below (adjust everything that you consider necessary):

```sql
mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `insert_xml_items`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `xml_items`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `temp_paysliptrans`,
     ->                      `temp_payslips`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp_payslips` (
    ->   `PayslipID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `PayrollRunID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ->   `isLive` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    ->   `print` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `EmployeeNumber` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `NINumber` VARCHAR(9) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`PayslipID`, `PayrollRunID`, `EmployeeNumber`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp_paysliptrans` (
    ->   `PayslipTranID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `PayslipID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `Name` VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `Type` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `Total` DECIMAL(10, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `Rate` DECIMAL(10, 4) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `Units` DECIMAL(10, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `YTD` DECIMAL(10, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`PayslipTranID`, `PayslipID`, `Type`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xml_items` (
    ->   `id` SERIAL,
    ->   `xml_item` LONGTEXT NOT NULL
    -> ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
    ->   '/path/to/file/PAYSLIPS37380004.xml'
    ->   INTO TABLE `xml_items`
    ->   CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    ->   LINES TERMINATED BY '</payslip>\n'
    ->   (@`xml_item`)
    ->   SET `xml_item` = @`xml_item`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE `xml_items`
    -> SET `xml_item` = CONCAT(`xml_item`, '</payslip>\n');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> DELIMITER $$

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_xml_items`()
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `xml_items` INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(`id`)
    ->                                             FROM `xml_items`);
    ->   DECLARE `current_xml_item` LONGTEXT;
    ->   DECLARE `xml_item_elements`,
    ->           `temp_payslips_PayslipID` INT UNSIGNED;
    ->   DECLARE `index_current_xml_item`,
    ->           `index_current_xml_item_element` INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;
    -> 
    ->   WHILE `index_current_xml_item` <= `xml_items` DO
    ->     SELECT `xml_item` INTO `current_xml_item`
    ->     FROM `xml_items`
    ->     WHERE `id` = `index_current_xml_item`;
    -> 
    ->     INSERT INTO `temp_payslips` (
    ->       `PayrollRunID`,
    ->       `isLive`,
    ->       `print`,
    ->       `NINumber`,
    ->       `EmployeeNumber`
    ->     ) VALUES (
    ->       1,
    ->       1,
    ->       0,
    ->       `ExtractValue`(`current_xml_item`,
    ->                      'payslip/employee/NINO'),
    ->       `ExtractValue`(`current_xml_item`,
    ->                      'payslip/employee/number')
    ->     );
    -> 
    ->     SELECT
    ->       LAST_INSERT_ID(),
    ->       `ExtractValue`(`current_xml_item`,
    ->       'COUNT(payslip/elements/element)'),
    ->       1
    ->     INTO
    ->       `temp_payslips_PayslipID`,
    ->       `xml_item_elements`,
    ->       `index_current_xml_item_element`;
    -> 
    ->     WHILE `index_current_xml_item_element` <= `xml_item_elements` DO
    ->       INSERT INTO `temp_paysliptrans` (
    ->         `PayslipID`,
    ->         `Name`,
    ->         `Type`,
    ->         `Total`,
    ->         `Rate`,
    ->         `Units`,
    ->         `YTD`
    ->       ) VALUES (
    ->         `temp_payslips_PayslipID`,
    ->         NULLIF(`ExtractValue`(`current_xml_item`,
    ->                               'payslip/elements/element[$index_current_xml_item_element]/attribute::title'),
    ->                ''),
    ->         'P',
    ->         NULLIF(`ExtractValue`(`current_xml_item`,
    ->                               'payslip/elements/element[$index_current_xml_item_element]/attribute::amount'),
    ->                ''),
    ->         NULLIF(`ExtractValue`(`current_xml_item`,
    ->                               'payslip/elements/element[$index_current_xml_item_element]/attribute::rate'),
    ->                ''),
    ->         NULLIF(`ExtractValue`(`current_xml_item`,
    ->                               'payslip/elements/element[$index_current_xml_item_element]/attribute::units'),
    ->                ''),
    ->         NULLIF(`ExtractValue`(`current_xml_item`,
    ->                               'payslip/elements/element[$index_current_xml_item_element]/attribute::ytd'),
    ->                '')
    ->       );
    ->       SET `index_current_xml_item_element` := `index_current_xml_item_element` + 1;
    ->     END WHILE;
    ->     SET `index_current_xml_item` := `index_current_xml_item` + 1;
    ->   END WHILE;
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `insert_xml_items`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `PayslipID`,
    ->   `PayrollRunID`,
    ->   `isLive`,
    ->   `print`,
    ->   `EmployeeNumber`,
    ->   `NINumber`
    -> FROM
    ->   `temp_payslips`;
+-----------+--------------+--------+-------+----------------+-----------+
| PayslipID | PayrollRunID | isLive | print | EmployeeNumber | NINumber  |
+-----------+--------------+--------+-------+----------------+-----------+
|         1 |            1 |      1 |     0 | 201567         | QQ104330Q |
+-----------+--------------+--------+-------+----------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `PayslipTranID`,
    ->   `PayslipID`,
    ->   `Name`,
    ->   `Type`,
    ->   `Total`,
    ->   `Rate`,
    ->   `Units`,
    ->   `YTD`
    -> FROM
    ->   `temp_paysliptrans`;
+---------------+-----------+-------------+------+---------+----------+-------+---------+
| PayslipTranID | PayslipID | Name        | Type | Total   | Rate     | Units | YTD     |
+---------------+-----------+-------------+------+---------+----------+-------+---------+
|             1 |         1 | Salary      | P    | 1572.62 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL |
|             2 |         1 | P.A.Y.E.    | P    | -470.00 |     NULL |  NULL | 1399.80 |
|             3 |         1 | Perf Bonus  | P    | 1741.00 |     NULL |  NULL |    NULL |
|             4 |         1 | N.I.        | P    | -312.84 |     NULL |  NULL |  994.34 |
|             5 |         1 | Unpaid Sick | P    |  -78.63 | -78.6300 |  1.00 |    NULL |
|             6 |         1 | RDC         | P    |   -1.00 |     NULL |  NULL |    3.00 |
+---------------+-----------+-------------+------+---------+----------+-------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `xml_items`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried the 1st option and it retrieves, but the problem is that it can only get data from the <employee> section.  I would like to also get data from the <address>, <employer>, <period>, <totals>, <notations> & <comments> sections.  The problem was that @name exists in the <employee> & <employer> sections but relates to temp_payslips.CompanyName & temp_payslips.EmployeeName

Comment: When I ran the 2nd query which deals with PayslipID I get the following error: Error Code: 1048. Column 'EmployeeNumber' cannot be null

Comment: @JamesKnight: [13.2.7 LOAD XML Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-xml.html) has limited functionality, you may not be able to do everything you need.

Comment: @JamesKnight: Do you have an empty `EmployeeNumber`?.

Comment: No.  I replaced `ExtractValue`(`current_xml_item`,
                      'payslip/employee/number') with 1 and ran the query and it completed OK, but the @NINO value wasn't inserted into the record so it doesn't seem to be getting either.

Comment: Just to emphasis that the problem seems to be that following command doesn't seem to be extracting the data from the XML. : `ExtractValue`(`current_xml_item`, 'payslip/employee/number')

Comment: @JamesKnight: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/77YrSgZCkFk91tjXUvjeun/0).